# Is $g(x,y)=\sin(y)/\sqrt{1+y^2/x^2}$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I want to check if the function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with

$$g(x,y)=\frac{\sin(y)}{\sqrt{1+y^2/x^2}}$$

for $x\neq0$, and $g(0,y)=0$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I've checked if $g$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, which seems to be true. But how to check if $g$ is differentiable there, too (in an efficient way)?

(and additionally: is $g$ differentiable at all the other points?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g(0,y)=0$ you have that $g_y(0,0)=0$ and since $g(x,0)=0$ you have that $g_x(0,0)=0$. To prove differentiability you need to check if the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{g(x,y)-g(0,0)-g_x(0,0)(x-0)-g_y(0,0)(y-0)}{\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}}$$ exists and is zero. As zhw. suggested in this case you get
$$\frac{g(x,y)-0-0-0}{\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}}=\frac{|x|\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}.$$
If you take the two restrictions $x=y$ and $y=0$ you will see that the limit cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The partial derivatives of $g$ at $(0,0)$ are both $0.$ If $g$ were differentiable at $(0,0),$ we would have

$$g(x,y) = 0 +0\cdot x + 0\cdot y +o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\,)$$

as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$ Do we have this?

Comment: Please write the answer that way that I know what you are doing and that I am able to apply your argument to other examples. Here I cannot tell, how you got your expression.

Comment: You down voted my answer?

Comment: Yes. I gave you the reason. There is a possibility to change to vote after the answer was edited.